# debounce closure shared by two functions

Tags: javascript, closures, debouncing

i am implementing debounce function. and i was able to successfully write the function then a confusing thought came to mind.

```
    function debounce(fn, timeout) {
        let timeoutRef;
        return function (...args) {
            const context = this;
            function cb() {
                fn.apply(context, args);
            }
            clearTimeout(timeoutRef);
            timeoutRef = setTimeout(cb, timeout);
        };
    }
    
    function foo() {
        console.log('foo is called');
    }
    function bar() {
        console.log('bar is called');
    }
    const debouncedFoo = debounce(foo, 10000);
    const debouncedBar = debounce(bar, 2000);
    
    debouncedFoo();  
    debouncedBar();
```

in the above code, don't **debouncedFoo** and **debouncedBar** share same colsure variable timeoutRef ?

if that's the case when **debouncedFoo()** it assigns setTimeout call reference to timeoutRef variable.
And later when **debouncedBar()** called previous timeoutRef set by **debouncedFoo()** call  should be be cleared and new setTimeout call reference should be assigned.

in conclusion,

expected result:

```
bar is called
```

actual result:

```
foo is called
bar is called
```

can someone please help me understand this ?

Comment: whats the value of timeoutRef when you call clearTimeout?

Comment: @JacobStephenson when  debouncedFoo() is called it's assigned with value of setTimeout(cb, timeout) where cb is function that calls foo after 1000ms

Comment: Right - but when debouncedBar() is called, what's the timeoutRef it's clearing? it's being reinitialized at the top of debounce()

Comment: Is your goal to have a single timeout for both functions... such that a successful call to one function cancels the call the later function?

Comment: "*don't debouncedFoo and debouncedBar share same colsure variable timeoutRef?*" - no they don't, since you did call `debounce()` twice, creating two separate closures. Notice they also different `timeout` variables.

Comment: Yes understood now, it’s not like I am calling inner function again but the denounce again which creates a fresh nee variables for inner function closure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in the above code, don't debouncedFoo and debouncedBar share same
> closure variable timeoutRef ?

No they not sharing the same closure. in fact function parameters "fn" and "timeout" are also bounded in closure scope it means there are there parameter which is bounded in closure scope

1. fn
2. timeout
3. timeoutRef

and because you are calling debounce function 2 times so every caller have their own local stack and local closure. another thing which is important is  `clearTimeout(timeoutRef);` here `timeoutRef` value is undefined so it will not work

Comment: clearTimeout(undefined) doesn’t throw error, I didn’t want to initialise tineoutRef with any other number because it can point an existing timeout